# Getting an error inTypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable

Tags: python, flask

I am using flask for my project and in the code, I don't get what type of error is showing me

If any mistake in my code then please let me know

```
@app.route("/predict", methods=['POST','GET'])
def pred():
    if request.method=='POST':
            query=request.form['query']
            count=request.form['num']
            fetched_tweets = get_tweets(api,query, count)
            return render_template('result.html', result = fetched_tweets)
```

[image]

Comment: That means `get_tweets` is returning `None`. If that's a function you wrote, you'll need to ensure it returns the results properly.

Comment: `fetched_tweets` is `None` try to pass optional value if your `get_tweets()` returns `None`